# Почему блок не сворачивается?

Tags: jquery

Изучаю jQuery и возникла проблема. Все работает как надо, но при повторном клике на элемент, чтобы его закрыть, ничего не происходит. Объясните в чем проблема, пожалуйста. Пример https://jsfiddle.net/gbuodsqp/

Понимаю, что проблема с пониманием функции $, но разобраться пока не получилось.

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
$('.item').removeClass('active');
$(this).parent('.item').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.item.active .menu{display:block}
.btn{background:red;margin-bottom:10px;padding:10px;cursor:pointer}
.menu{display:none;background:green;margin-bottom:10px;padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="btn">Меню 1</div>
  <div class="menu">Меню 1 работает</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="btn">Меню 2</div>
   <div class="menu">Меню 2 работает</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="btn">Меню 3</div>
  <div class="menu">Меню 3 работает</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.item').removeClass('active');
```

убирает класс `active`, у всех `item`.

```
$(this).parent('.item').toggleClass('active');
```

Данная же строка переключает класс `active` для родителя. Поскольку вы предварительно сняли класс у всех, то у родителя его уже тоже нет, и данная строка его добавляет обратно.

Как вывод тут - надо снимать `active` не у всех item, а у всех кроме родительского, то есть у соседних элементов. То есть как-то так

```
$(this).closest('.item').toggleClass('active')
       .siblings('.item').removeClass('active')
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, есть еще один вопрос. Если кнопки для открытия меню, будут в разных родительских блоках, то как контролировать их закрытие? Я понимаю, что здесь поиск идет только в родительском блоке, а как выйти за его пределы? Буду очень благодарен. Много чего перепробовал  но ничего толкового не вышло. Вот пример - https://jsfiddle.net/9y8ns7m4/

Comment: В последствии я пришел вот к такому вот результату - https://jsfiddle.net/8pbnag0k/ . Все работает, хотелось узнать на сколько это правильно.

Comment: @Васёчег если у вас в каждом group только один item, то не ясно зачем такая верстка нужна, добавляйте active сразу к group. А если нет, так показывайте пример более приближенный к реальности, например, с двумя item в группе

Comment: @Васёчег но в любом случаев, лучше найти `closest('.group')` и сделать что-то вроде `$('.group').not($group).find('.item.active').removeClass('active)`, ибо использование прямых связей с родителями сломается при небольшом изменении верстки.